# How to data to Array using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need object to convert to array and push to array.
Depending on what is chosen, I get it like this ->

```
{
 firstUnit: {label: 'caca', value: 70}
 secondUnit: {label: 'Parent 2', value: 9}
}
```

Or sometimes i got only

```
{
 firstUnit: {label: 'caca', value: 70} 
}
```

or

```
{ 
 secondUnit: {label: 'Parent 2', value: 9}
}
```

What I need ?

I need to convert this

```
{
 firstUnit: {label: 'caca', value: 70}
 secondUnit: {label: 'Parent 2', value: 9}
}
```

or

```
{
 firstUnit: {label: 'caca', value: 70} 
}
```

TO

```
 [ {label: 'caca', value: 70} , {label: 'Parent 2', value: 9}]
```

or if only one object

```
 [{label: 'caca', value: 70}]
```

What I am try ?

```
let formVal = [formValues];
let newVal = [formVal?.map((values) => values)]
```

This is no work property.

Comment: Use `const newVal = Object.entries(formValues);` might help you.

Answer (score 3):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will work here.

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values

```js
const data = {
 firstUnit: { label: 'caca', value: 70 },
 secondUnit: { label: 'Parent 2', value: 9 }
};

const out = Object.values(data);

console.log(out);
```